# Scala case class with cyclic referencing and value updation

Tags: scala

Im trying to understand the following code, how the value in the variables `a` of case class dummy is being updated in the following code.

In the `value` method, I'm assigning the value of `a` to `b` , and adding new Node to `b`, which inturn it is reflecting the changes in `a` also. I don't understand how the value is `a` is being changed without even re-assignement.

```
object test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    case class abc(str: String, var ele: abc)

    case class dummy(a: abc) {
      def value() = {
        var b = a
        println(s"Value of B before changing : ${b.str}") // Value of B before changing : Good
        println(s"Value of A before changing : ${a.str}") // Value of A before changing : Good
        val newObj = abc(" Morning", null)
        b.ele = newObj
        println(s"Value of A After changing : ${a.str},${a.ele.str}") // Value of A After changing : Good, Morning
        println(s"Value of B after changing : ${b.str},${b.ele.str}") // Value of B after changing : Good, Morning
      }
    }

    val testObj = dummy(abc("Good", null))
    testObj.value()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var b = a
```

This does not make a copy.

You now have both variables pointing to the same object, and any change made to the state of `b` will also reflect in `a`.

For this (and other reasons) you are highly encouraged to avoid mutable state. If your case class did not have a `var` in it, it would be immutable and you can be sure that no matter who you give your `a` to, it will still be intact when you get it back.

(The second bad habit to shake is using `null`. No need for that in Scala, make the type an `Option` instead).

Comment: as you have said , `var b = a` 'doesn't make a copy' is this statement valid only for case class with contains mutable fields.

Comment: It is the same for all objects (including arrays). A `=` just assigns pointers to objects to another variable (which will then refer to the same object, not to a copy).

Comment: I tried the same for this code `var a = 2;
 var b = a;
 b = 3;
 println(a,b) // (2,3) `, according to statement it should update the value in a also, but it is not doing .

Comment: `b = 3` does not update the object that `b` is pointing to. It sets `b` to another value. That does not affect other variables (like `a`) that happen to also contain the old value. Your original code had `b.ele = newObj` (NOT `b = newObj`). That kept `b` pointing at the same object (which `a` was also looking at), but updated `ele` *inside* of that object (and thus, also `a.ele` which at that point was just another name/variable/label for the same thing).

Comment: Read this (even though it is about Java, the same applies to Scala): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?noredirect=1&lq=1 It is important to understand that an object and a variable pointing to the object are not the same thing.